# get all ip addresses getAllAdresses() method

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm writing a program and i actually have a problem a time running. There's this instruction to get all IP of a sub network from first address and last address.

```
    SubnetInfo info = utils.getInfo();
    List<String> ips = new ArrayList((Arrays.asList(info.getAllAddresses()));
```

The problem when i run debug, there's a list that needs to be filled by 16777214 Strings.Is there any other way to implement the method of SubnetInfo getAllAddresses() to have eclipse running faster ??

Comment: Is there any alternative to write program which will get me all the ip adresses from First Address: [1.0.0.1]
Last Address: [1.255.255.254] this range and wouldn't take time ? What do you recommend ?

Comment: Where is the problem is it in instantiating a String array of 16777214 strings? or filling a new list with a new list with that effective size ?